# pycodestyle retrieve results without printing them

Tags: python, pycodestyle

I'm trying to use `pycodestyle` within a python program:

```
from pycodestyle import StyleGuide, StandardReport

CONFIG_FILE = 'setup.cfg'


def check_pycodestyle():
    style_guide = StyleGuide(config_file=CONFIG_FILE, quiet=True)
    # style_guide = StyleGuide(config_file=CONFIG_FILE, reporter=StandardReport, quiet=True)
    report = style_guide.check_files(paths='./')
```

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to get the results as a simple return value. When using the `quiet=True` flag, nothing is printed automatically but the returned report is a `BaseReport` and doesn't seem to contain the actual results but just a count on how many `total_errors`.

When omitting the `quiet` flag, then the results are automatically printed.

Is there a function to retrieve the results and not print them?

EDIT:
When using `report.get_file_results()` I receive the following results:

With `quiet=True`:

```
0
```

Without `quiet`:

```
<prints the results>
0
```

Comment: Give an example of what `report.get_file_results()` returns

Comment: I added the output

Answer (score 0):

Since the results are 'print'ed, you can just redirect the print like:

```
sys.stdout = open(r'C:/YourResultFilePath/Filename.txt', 'w')  # this is 'w' so the previous file is replaced
```

I would recommend saving the sys.stdout so you can restore it at the end of your code:

old_stdout = sys.stdout

Then:

sys.stdout = old_stdout